# How to assess textarea character length in another DOM element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to subtract the current string length of a textarea from its maxlength then feed the output to another tag on the page. Individually, the values I'm evaluating do return correct values and but if I log or try using their sum, the value of the textarea stays stagnant. Here's my markup

```
<textarea maxlength='10'>init</textarea> <br>
<span id='count'></span> </br>
```

Then in my js, I have

```
var max = parseInt($("textarea").attr("maxlength")), len = $("textarea").val().length, currLen = max - len-1;

$(document).ready(function() {
$('#count').html(currLen);
});

$("textarea").on('input', function(){
console.log(currLen);
$("#count").html(currLen);
});
```

Please what am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to reevaluate the input value's length every time the input changes, like so:

```
var max = parseInt($("textarea").attr("maxlength")),
  len = $("textarea").val().length,
  currLen = max - len - 1;  

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#count').html(currLen);
});

$("textarea").on('input', function() {
  max = parseInt($("textarea").attr("maxlength"));
  len = $("textarea").val().length;
  currLen = max - len - 1;  
  console.log(currLen);
  $("#count").html(currLen);
});
```

Otherwise you're only ever referencing the value that the variable was initialized with

Answer (score 1):

You are not recalculating the values. try:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

     var max = parseInt($("textarea").attr("maxlength"));


    $("textarea").on('input', function(){
     var len = $("textarea").val().length, currLen = max - len-1
     console.log(currLen);
     $("#count").html(currLen);
    }).trigger("input"); //once to start
});
```

Comment: +1 for the concise solution. How am I able to attack the trigger method to the `on` method? From what I understand from the jQuery site, it should only be called on the node requiring the event to be triggered but here I see you attaching it to the on input callback

Comment: You should review the jQuery docs. Unless the function returns a specific value -- like `$(".selector").val()` -- jQuery functions return themselves to allow function chaining. e.g. `$(".selector").on('click', function...).on('change', ...).addClass('hi').show();` all of on...on... addClass...show are being called on the same $(".selector") object

Answer (score 0):

I think you shoud recount the currLen value first before you log in the input callback function